# A question regarding the given rates in a related rates question

Tags: derivatives, applications

I have a question about these rates given in a related rates question. For example, when it's given that the car is moving at $60\;\text{km/h}$, a balloon is heading up at $2\;\text{m/s}$, a circle's radius is increasing by $5\;\text{cm/s}$, assuming that every property of what I've mentioned is a function of time $(t)$, (distance driven, height, radius) is a function of time, would the derivative of them be the same value for all $t$?

In other words, are these function linear? so that the slope of the curve for all $t$ is the same? Does this imply that the car would of driven $120\;\text{km/s}$ at $t = 2$, or the radius is $10\;\text{cm/s}$ at $t = 2$?

Comment: I'm stating examples on rates that can be given a function. I only want to know that these rates of change are constant for every (t) such that "t" is a specific time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speeds are all constant in this problem.  You need to define the units of $t$ that you are using.  If $t$ is measured in hours, a car moving at $60\;\text{km/h}$ will have moved $120\; \text{km}$.  It will not be moving at $120\;\text{km/h}$.  The same is true for the other cases.  You multiply the rate by time to get the position.  You need to make sure the units are consistent, so again if $t$ is in hours at $t=2$ the balloon has climbed $7200\; \text m$

Comment: Yeah. This is what I'm trying to get to, that all these rates are the same at every (t).

Comment: They usually are, but you have to read the question.  Sometimes the rate of change is given as something like $2+5t\; \text{m/sec}$, then it is not constant.

Comment: True. That would be an instant change at some (t), I have to find it first then continue the solution.